# Aligning pandas DataFrames that don't have a common index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have DataFrames that represent data from two different sensors:

```
In[0]: df0
Out[0]:
   time  foo  
0   0.1  123  
1   1.0  234  
2   2.1  345
3   3.1  456  
4   3.9  567  
5   5.1  678  

In[0]: df1
Out[0]:
   time  bar  
0  -0.9  876  
1  -0.1  765  
2   0.7  654  
3   2.1  543  
4   3.0  432
```

The sensors provide a measure (`foo` or `bar`) and a timestamp (`time`) for each events that they are monitoring. A couple things to note:

1. the timestamps are close, but not identical
2. the range over which data was collected is different across sensors (i.e. they were turned on and turned off independently)

I'm trying to align `df0` and `df1` to get the following:

```
In[3]: df3
Out[3]:
   time_df0  foo  time_df1  bar  
0       nan  nan       -0.9  876
1       0.1  123       -0.1  765
2       1.0  234        0.7  654
3       2.1  345        2.1  543
4       3.1  456        3.0  432
5       3.9  567        nan  nan
6       5.1  678        nan  nan
```

Comment: To get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201618/pandas-merge-match-the-nearest-time-stamp-the-series-of-timestamps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614474/pandas-merge-on-name-and-closest-date Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491840/merging-two-pandas-dataframes-on-nearest-time-stamp

Comment: @ajwood, is your `time` column of `datetime` dtype?

Comment: @MaxU no, it's a float offset (in seconds) from when the sensor was turned on; the only reason the times are close between sensors is because I've done other processing for to determine find that offset. Now I just need to to create a common index

Comment: @ajwood, your sample data sets are absolutely fine. I thought that your `time` column is of `datetime` dtype - that's why i asked you to change your sample data sets (just ignore my first comment)...

Answer (score 1):

[@Kartik posted a perfect links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475968/aligning-pandas-dataframes-that-dont-have-a-common-index?noredirect=1#comment66271493_39475968) to start with...

Here is a starting point:

```
df0.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)

In [36]: df1.reindex(df0.index, method='nearest').join(df0)
Out[36]:
      bar  foo
time
0.1   765  123
1.0   654  234
2.1   543  345
3.1   432  456
3.9   432  567
5.1   432  678
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the leading and trailing rows "follow" the new index (i.e. the `nan` values in my example)?

Comment: A brute-force solution could be trying several integer offsets on the original index, minimize the difference between timestamps, then merging of the optimal index offset.

Comment: @ajwood, sorry, currently i don't see any elegant solution for not-matching rows...

Comment: no problem - these datasets will be small, so the brute force solution should work for me. I'll add an answer once I have something concise to report